# Something weird with Stock chart in excel

Tags: charts, excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a VBA code in excel which automatically creates agraph and format it and then paste in into the chart excel sheet. The code seems to work fine for all graphs except the stock graph. Whenever I run the macro, I can see the chart creation but when it comes to formatting and specially pasting, the graph becomes invisibel. In other words, I cant see the graph when code finishes running.

I dont know what is going on with the stock graph? Can anyone explain and tell me a solution to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Here is my code:

```
Sub CreateGraph()
Dim MyRng As Range
Dim LastCell As Long
LastCell = Worksheets(1).Range("E3").End(xlDown).Row
Set MyRng = Worksheets(1).Range("B3:E" & LastCell)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=MyRng
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlStockHLC
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Chart1"
End Sub

Sub FormatChart()
Let Title = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = Title & "responses*"
    With ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Size = 8
    End With
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 7
    End With
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 7
    End With
    With ActiveChart.PlotArea.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 2
    .PatternColorIndex = 1
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    End With
    Range("S4").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=48
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    With ActiveChart.Legend.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 8
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=45
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-45
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-54
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width = 500
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Height = 1000
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 100
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 20
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 10
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 51, 153)
    End With
            With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(80, 116, 77)
    End With
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Chart2").Select
    ActiveChart.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: You might get better responses if you post some of your code.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I have posted my code Above.

Answer (score 0):

Nupur,

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

Replace the code

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
Selection.Cut
Sheets("Chart2").Select
ActiveChart.Paste
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Chart2"
```

**SUGGESTION**: I believe you recorded a macro? :) This two piece of the code does the same thing :) Excel that ways is pretty 'humble' You just need to tell it once ;)

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
```

and this

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
```

You can safely delete the extra lines.

HTH

Sid

Comment: @ Sid: Thanks for your response. The code is working fine but is giving an error: "The specific dimension is not valid for current chart type". On debugging it highlights the line: ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Chart2"

Comment: @Nupur: I tested the code and it is working fine. For a speedy solution can you upload your file in www.wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: Hi Sid! I kind of figured out why is the code giving me a run time error. When I change the Name:="Chart2" to Name:="Sheet1", the code works abosulutely fine. but i still need the graph to be saved on "chart" sheet and not the regular sheet.